# MIT Scheme Message Passing Abstraction

Tags: scheme

In a Computer Science course I am taking, for homework, we were tasked with several different questions all pertaining to message passing. I have been able to solve all but one, which asks for the following:

> Write a mailman object factory `(make-mailman)` that takes in no parameters and
>   returns a message-passing object that responds to the following messages:
>
> - `'add-to-route`: return a procedure that takes in an arbitrary number of mailbox objects
>     and adds them to the mailman object's “route”
> - `'collect-letters`: return a procedure that takes in an arbitrary number of letter objects and
>     collects them for future distribution
> - `'distribute`: add each of the collected letters to the mailbox on the mailman's route whose
>     address matches the letter's destination and return a list of any letters whose destinations
>     did not match any mailboxes on the route (Note: After each passing of
>     `'distribute`
>     the
>     mailman object should have no collected letters.)

Some remarks that are given to make the code easier include:

- If multiple letters are distributed to the same mailbox in one distribution round, any one
  of them may be the “latest” letter whose message is returned by passing `'get-latest-message`
  to the mailbox.
- No two mailboxes will have the same address.
- No mailbox or letter will be passed to the mailman more than once.
- The bad letters returned by distribute do not need to be in a specific order.
- Use the `. args` syntax for accepting arbitrary amount of arguments.

This is what I have been able to figure out for myself:

```
(define (make-mailman)
  (let ((T '()))
    (define (route-adder . mobjects)
      (assoc mobjects T))
    (define (letter-collecter . lobjects)
      (assoc lobjects T))
    (define (add-to-route mobjects)
      (begin (set! T (cons (route-adder . mobjects) T)) 'done))
    (define (collect-letters lobjects)
      (begin (set! T (cons (sort-strings (letter-collecter . lobjects)) T)) 'done))
    (define (dispatch z)
      (cond ((eq? z 'add-to-route) add-to-route)
        ((eq? z 'collect-letters) collect-letters)
        ((eq? z 'distribute) "unsure of what to do here")
        (else "Invalid option")))
    dispatch))
```

Any help that can be given to me here will be appreciated, as I have tried looking at this problem for a while, and cannot figure out what to do from here.

Comment: What does the title have to do with this?  Suggest "Scheme Message Passing Abstraction"

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Changed title to make more sense.

Comment: Changing your question as you did is confusing, because the answers here refer to your previous code. This Q/A entry is now impossible to understand. I have reverted your question to its previous version, and if you want, you can ask a new question with your new code.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you for that. I'm not used to making edits on here, so I guess I made some mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has all kinds of mix-ups. :) Let's proceed step by step.

The `dispatch` bit is almost OK:

```
(define (make-mailman)
 (let ...
  ...
  (define (dispatch msg)                ;; use short but suggestive var names
   (cond 
    ((eq? msg 'add-to-route)    add-to-route)
    ((eq? msg 'collect-letters) collect-letters)
    ((eq? msg 'distribute) 
       ;; "unsure of what to do here" <<-- Distribute the letters, what else?
                                distribute-the-letters)
    (else "Invalid option")))
  dispatch))
```

With such objects, a sample call will be `(define ob (make-mailman))` and then `((ob 'add-to-route) box1 box2 ... boxn)` etc. So `add-to-route` procedure must be defined this way:

```
(define (make-mailman)
 (let ((self (list '(ROUTE)           ; each mailman has a route, and a mailbag
                   '(MAILBAG))))      ; use suggestive name here (T, what T?)
  ...
  (define (add-to-route . mailboxes)
    (let ((route (assoc 'ROUTE self))) 
      (set-cdr! route
          (append mailboxes           ; there will be no duplicates
            (cdr route)))
      'DONE))
```

Right? Same with the letters:

```
  (define (collect-letters . letters)
    (let ((mailbag (assoc 'MAILBAG self)))
      .....
      'DONE))
```

Now we can deal with the missing part, `distribute-the-letters`:

```
  (define (distribute-the-letters)
    ;; for each letter in my mailbag
    (let* ((mailbag (assoc 'MAILBAG self))
           (mailboxes (cdr (assoc 'ROUTE self)))
           (letters (cdr mailbag)))
      (if (null? letters) ()
        (let loop ((letter  (car letters))
                   (letters (cdr letters))
                   (not-delivered ()))
    ;;   access its address, 
          (let* ((address (letter 'get-address))
            ;; (we assume it supports this interface, 
            ;;   or maybe that's part of a previous assignment)
    ;;     and find a mailbox on my route such that
                 (mbx (find-mailbox address mailboxes)))
    ;;     its address matches the letter's
    ;;     and if so,
             (if .....
    ;;        put that letter into this mailbox: 
               ((mbx 'put-letter) letter)
    ;;            (we assume it supports this interface, 
    ;;             or maybe that's part of a previous assignment)
    ;;     but if not, add letter to the "not-delivered" list
               ..... )
            (if (null? letters)
    ;; having emptied the mailbag, return the "not-delivered" list
              (begin (set-cdr! mailbag nil) not-delivered)
              (loop (car letters) (cdr letters) not-delivered)))))))
```

We assume that both `letter` and `mailbox` objects support the message type `'get-address` to which they both return the same comparable `address` type of object, and that `mailbox` objects support `'put-letter` message.

Comment: Thank you very much for adding some clarification on what I was doing wrong. I did try using your code (current up above), but I'm noticing a strange error when I try to run it. It says the the object distribute-the-letters, passed as an argument to length, is not a list. I'm not sure why it's saying that, since all that is being passed in are lists (at least, from what I can see).

Comment: @Gabe `distribute-the-letters` in my code is supposed to be a function. as seen here: `(define (distribute-the-letters) ...`. You shouldn't use tab characters here on SO in your code, it confuses the indentation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a bit confused as to your answer here. I don't understand why tab characters would be a problem if everything is spaced correctly and in the correct environment.

Comment: @Gabe you latest code looked unevenly indented, that's all. It just makes it hard to read it, the correctness of course depends on parentheses alone. -- I've rolled back your latest edit, because these answers here respond to the previous version of your code. Your new code is very different from the previous version; since you have questions about your new code, you really should ask a new question, starting with your latest version. :)

Answer (score 2):

Other than the specifics of the message functionality, it looks like you've nailed it.  There are however some errors:

This `(route-adder . mobjects)` should be `(router-adder objects)` and similarly for `(letter-collector . lobjects)`.

The use of `begin` is unneeded.  The body of a `(define (func . args) <body> ...)` is implicitly enclosed in a `begin`.

Idiomatically your code could be written as:

```
(define (make-mailman)
  (let ((T '()))
    ;; ...
    (lambda (z)
      (case z
        ((add-to-route)    add-to-route)
        ((collect-letters) collect-letters)
        ((distribute)      distribute)
        (else (error "Invalid option"))))))
```

[but you may not know about `case` nor `lambda` yet...]

As for solving the actual messaging functionality.  You are going to need to maintain a set of mailboxes where each mailbox is going to hold a set of letters.  A letter will presumably consist of an address and some content (extra credit for a return-address).  The distribute behavior will check the address on each letter and deposit it in its mailbox.  The mailman will need to hold letters (while on his route collecting-letters) until instructed to distribute.

For this you might start by building up the lower-levels of the functionality and then using the lower-levels to build up the actual message passing functionality.  Starting like, for example:

```
(define (make-letter addr content)
  `(LETTER ,addr ,content))
(define letter-addr cadr)
;; ...

(define (make-mailbox addr)
  '(MBOX ,addr))
(define mailbox-letters cddr)
(define (mailbox-letters-add mailbox letter)
  (set-cdr! (cdr mailbox) (cons letter (mailbox-letters mailbox))))

;;...
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but for the apply procedure you mention, I tried implementing that into the code, but it just returned an error that apply was being used incorrectly. Did you mean for something else to be changed as well?

Comment: Updated; looks like `(router-adder objects)` (without the `.`) is sufficient.