# How does Scheme abstract data?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, scheme, lambda-calculus, abstract-data-type

In statically typed language, people are able to use algebraic data type to abstract data and also generate constructors, or use class, trait and mixin to deal with data abstraction.

In dynamically typed language, like Python and Ruby, they all provide a class system to users.

But what about scheme, the simplest functional language, the closest one to λ-calculi, how does it abstract data?

Do scheme programmers usually just put data in a list or a lambda abstraction, and write some accessor function to make it look like a tree or something else? like [EOPL](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/essentials-programming-languages) says: **specifying data via interfaces**.

And then how does this abstraction technique relate to abstract data type (ADT) and objects? with regard to [On understanding data abstraction, revisited](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1640089.1640133).

Comment: Probably with function encodings. A data type can be fully defined by the recursion scheme for reducing it (Church, Böhm-Berarducci). Alternatively. you can fully define it by pattern matching (Scott). In the context of functions pattern matching means to pass the right _constructor_ function.

Comment: thanks for pointing out function encoding, and about Scott's pattern matching, could you provide more references? @IvenMarquardt

Comment: Nothing scheme related, but [24 Days of GHC Extensions: Rank N Types](https://ocharles.org.uk/guest-posts/2014-12-18-rank-n-types.html) captures the general idea quite well

Comment: @IvenMarquardt Thanks, it indeed gives me insight of datatype

Comment: "_Do scheme programmers usually just put data in a list or a lambda abstraction,...._" -- standard Scheme also has record types which are like structs, and many Scheme implementations have an object system, often modeled on the powerful CLOS of Common Lisp.

Comment: the old bare-bones way is to create closures (that hold and hide the data) which respond to "messages" and thus become "objects". (something about "Scheme [mailboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430154/849891)".) regarding abstract data types, the usual answer I always see is modules (hiding the implementations in them). probably ML is the most sophisticated language in that regard.

Comment: Most mainstream statically typed languages don't have sum types, so calling them "algebraic" is stretching it. Also, not all dynamically typed languages have a class system. I suspect that you're generalizing a lot from very few special (and object-oriented) cases.

Comment: @molbdnilo what do you mean re sum types? googling "sum types" brings up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union#Timeline_of_language_support which lists a lot of languages, among them ML, Haskell, C, C++, Rust, Swift, Scala, F# ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What SICP (and I guess, EOPL) is advocating is just using functions to access data; then you can always switch one set of functions for another, implementing the same named set of functions to work with another concrete implementation. And *that* (i.e. the sets of such functions) is what forms the "interfaces", and *that*'s what you put in different source files, and by just loading the appropriate one you can switch the concrete implementation while all the other code is none the wiser. *That's* what makes it "abstract" datatype.

As for the *algebraic* data types, the old bare-bones Scheme way is to create closures (that hold and hide the data) which respond to "messages" and thus become "objects" (something about "Scheme [mailboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430154/849891)"). This gives us products, i.e. records, and functions we get for free from Scheme itself. For sum types, just as in C/C++, we can use [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) in a disciplined manner (or, again, hide the specifics behind a set of "interface" functions).

EOPL has something called "variant-case" which handles such sum types in a manner similar to pattern matching. Searching brings up e.g. [this link](https://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/mailarch/plt-scheme-2000/msg00039.html) saying

> *I'm using DrScheme w/ the EOPL textbook, which uses `define-record` and `variant-​case`. I've got the macro definitions from the PLT site, but am now dealing with ...*

so seems relevant, as one example.